# Deleting directory that contains items

Tags: c#, directory, cmd

I am trying to delete a directory using C#. The first method I tried was

```
Directory.Delete(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Qmuzki32");
```

I get an exception stating that the directory is not empty. I then found a cmd command which I can use to delete the directory quietly regardless of the fact that the directory is empty or not. I ran the following command in cmd:

```
rmdir /s /q "C:/Program Files (x86)/Qmuzik32"
```

This worked and did exactly what I wanted it to do. With my first attempt I tried building this command into a C# process like so:

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Qmuzik32"))
   {
       string sQM32Folder = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Qmuzik32";
       Process del = new Process();
       del.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
       del.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("rmdir /s /q \"{0}\"", sQM32Folder);
       del.WaitForExit();
   }
```

This did not work and then I tried it like this:

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Qmuzik32"))
   {
       string sQM32Folder = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Qmuzik32";
       Process del = new Process();
       del.StartInfo.FileName = "rmdir.exe";
       del.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/s /q \"{0}\"", sQM32Folder);
       del.WaitForExit();
   }
```

Same problem. I get the exception:

```
No process is associated with this object.
```

I do think I am on the right track; maybe the code above just requires some tweaking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [Directory.Delete(string, bool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx).

While the low-level filesystem APIs of course require you to make sure the directory is empty first, any half-decent framework abstracting them allows you do do a recursive delete. In fact, existence of such a method *would be the first thing I'd check before even trying to resort to external programs*.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the cmd way you can use this:

```
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
Info.Arguments = "/C rd /s /q \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Qmuzik32\""; 
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
Info.CreateNoWindow = true; 
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe"; 
Process.Start(Info);
```

Comment: I don't think locals should be title-cased in C# ;)

Comment: Yeah, they shouldn't, quick typing :)

Comment: This method works for sure. Any other methods that I tried failed at some point and gave me a System.IO error.

Answer (score 4):

```
del.Start();
del.WaitForExit();
```

you didn't start the procces so it doesn't have a PID so it dies

Comment: @Joey It still isn't the real answer because of that rmdir isn't a executable but just a command inside cmd so :/

Comment: That's what they tried first (which fails for the same reason). So I'd still say your answer is relevant. Except of course that you shouldn't try recursively deleting a directory this way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
ps.CreateNoWindow = true;
ps.UseShellExecute = false;
ps.FileName = "cmd";
ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
ps.Arguments = "/c rmdir /s/q \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Qmuzik32\"";
ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

`Directory.Delete(path, true)` does not work if any of the files contain read-only files. Only using `rmdir` like this will remove the directory and all of its contents.